# Time profiling code inside of Blocks

Tags: objective-c, profiling, objective-c-blocks, instruments

How do I use Instruments to profile the code inside a Block? Right now I am only able to see the total time for the Block, but not able to go inside the block to see where time is consumed.

As examples, case 1:

```
if (completionBlock) {
    completionBlock(mutableManagedObjects, mutableBackingObjects);
}
```

and case 2:

```
[backingContext performBlockAndWait:^{

    if (backingObjectID) {

        backingObject = [backingContext existingObjectWithID:backingObjectID error:nil];
    } else {
        backingObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entity.name inManagedObjectContext:backingContext];

    }
}];
```

In case 1, I am not able to profile inside the function and find out the time consumed; it just shows the total time for the Block. In case 2 also, I am just getting the % of the total Block; it doesn't show the details for the lines of code inside.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate blocks and check profile of each.

```
/*! \brief check first for backingContext as it is not set yet up here
if (backingObjectID) {

    [backingContext performBlockAndWait:^{

        backingObject = [backingContext existingObjectWithID:backingObjectID error:nil];
    }];

} else {

    [backingContext performBlockAndWait:^{

    backingObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entity.name inManagedObjectContext:backingContext];
    }];

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now go inside a block starting from **Xcode 6.0.1**.